# Alternative to print and cat

Tags: r

Having a bit of a mental block. I am sure I found a function to print iteration numbers in a `for` loop that was not `print` and not `cat`, but gave the same output as cat below.

```
> for(i in 10^(1:5))  print(i)
[1] 10
[1] 100
[1] 1000
[1] 10000
[1] 1e+05
> for(i in 10^(1:5))  cat(i, "\n")
10 
100 
1000 
10000 
1e+05
```

I cannot see any reference to it in the R help files for print and cat. Tried googling for it, but not getting anywhere.

Comment: So what's wrong with using `cat()`?

Comment: nothing really, just the function I remember seeing you did not have to worry about "\n", which I always mess up.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's easy enough to define a wrapper function around `cat`:

```
catn <- function(x, append="\n"){cat(x); cat(append)}
```

Use it:

```
for(i in 10^(1:5))  catn(i)
10
100
1000
10000
1e+05
```

Or you can use `message` (which has the added benefit that in some code editors, e.g. Eclipse, the messages appear in a different colour):

```
for(i in 10^(1:5))  message(i)
10
100
1000
10000
1e+05
```

Comment: In addition, message is piped to stderr not stdout, and they can easily be suppressed using supressMessages. It is a logical companion of stop and warning, which yield an error or a warning.

Comment: My comments on cats in R in the bottom of this page: http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/output/

Answer (score 3):

Turns out `write` can also write to standard output too if `file == ""`:

```
> for (i in 10^(1:5)) write(i, "")
10
100
1000
10000
1e+05
```

The default value of `file` is `"data"` though.

(I am also searching for this missing operator for a long time :D)